# Banned from reviewing for justified decisions - should I refrain from reviewing?

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

I recently got banned from reviewing suggested edits.

> You reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15882296, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15881736 and https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15882090 incorrectly. They did not add any significant changes. Please pay more attention to each review in future

1. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15882296 was approved by me, but rejected by three other users, reason: *"This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible."*  **I disagree.** Although the question is a duplicate and of bad quality, putting the central question in its own line makes it more accessible to everyone.
2. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15881736 was rejected by three users saying *"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit."* **I strongly disagree**; this *is* a very useful edit, as it adds the actual code (`$('.day').attr("disabled","")`) that the answer is talking about. Without this line of code the complete answer is much much less valuable.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15882090  was approved by me and another >20k rep user, it was rejected by three ~2k users; reason: *"This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible."* In my opinion the edit **is justified** as it makes the for-loop easily recognizable on first sight.

While the two "no improvement" edits are strongly opinion based and cannot be right or wrong, the second edit is actually completely justified.

So, in all three cases I would judge exactly the same way again.

Given that it can apparently happen to be banned from reviewing for making no wrong decision at all, I personally see two options:

1. Not doing any reviewing anymore. After all, there is no profit for me doing this. It's a service to the community and if the community thinks I'm not good at it, why should I do it?!
2. Next time simply hit the "Approve & Edit" or "Reject & Edit" button and directly nail the edit without the danger to be banned.

Which one should I use?

Comment: Your 1 and 3 are the same link. That is a bad edit IMO. It adds a tag to the title and the other change doesn't improve the post at all. If worth doing anything at all the last line could have been entirely removed as noise.

Comment: Tags don't belong into the title (edit 1) and if you really think that `for` loop should be separated visually, then reject and edit that bad suggestion which worsened the indentation(edit 3). Reject (and edit) is the only suitable option for these two. (I don't have an opinion about edit 2)

Comment: *"Next time simply hit the "Approve & Edit" or "Reject & Edit" button and directly nail the edit without the danger to be banned."* A mod banned you this time and can also ban you next time. So this behaviour is just immature and won't protect your from being banned.

Comment: We also received a flag complaining about your approval of this tag wiki edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15874928 , which consisted of plagiarized content, but there probably wasn't enough space in the review ban message to add that. I wasn't the one who banned you from review, but all these together looked to me like a pattern of inattentive reviewing.

Answer (score 32):

> While the two "no improvement" edits are strongly opinion based and cannot be right or wrong...

Oh, ***but they are.***  They are *very* wrong.  Let's start here.

In [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15882296), the only significant thing added was more metadata to the question.  Nothing more, nothing less.  The question is *tagged* with C++; why would one feel the need to add C++ to the question?  Worse, why isn't it properly capitalized?  The line about them being a newbie could've been deleted too, since we really aren't looking at their skill level when they're asking a question.

As a reviewer, we expect you to look at these kinds of things more critically.

In [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15882090), only whitespace formatting changes were made.  Truthfully this edit would've been fine to do if the user were 2k+ rep, but the real issue is it doesn't really improve the question much.  It doesn't add much clarity to the question and it isn't like the question's code was *horribly* formatted, either.  Not the best kind of change to make in a review queue.

> ...the second edit is actually completely justified.

But it wasn't.  [The edit you made](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15881736) was a ***comment***.  It was a remark on a post.  You should have left it as a comment on the answer.  At worst, you could've left your *own* answer with that as it.  (It might not have done *well*, but it would've been better than what you did.)

Honestly?  It may be good for you to take a break from reviewing.  If you're not feeling very good about how your last reviews went down, it's fine if you step away from it.

If you ever want to jump back into it, look around on Meta to get more context into what other reviewers have done, and what the general consensus is on other reviews.  If you're ever confused on what to do, ***don't be afraid to skip the review***.

Comment: *"In this edit, only whitespace formatting changes were made"* We shouldn't ignore that this edit worsens the indentation. So it is not only superfluous, but also a bad edit.

Comment: Also, only-whitespace edits are fine so long as they make the content _objectively_ easier to read and understand. That's the main goals of the review process.

Answer (score 8):

I would have rejected all three suggested edits, but I don't agree that you have simply two options.  [I'll admit I'm not editor-friendly.]

It's the second edit you contest most.  I'd strike that one down for the following reasons:

1. It's a comment;
2. It isn't formatted correctly as code;
3. It doesn't flow in the writing.

If I were tempted to hit "approve" on that one, I'd want to at least improve it for those latter.  Yes, that would make my decision unilateral but that isn't the reason for "improving".

Should you take a break?  That depends on your motivation.  I'll go along with the idea that in this question you are after self-improvement rather than complaining that your pride is hurt.

Reviewing is good.  That you question feedback is good.

Out of your two choices, go for the first.  "Reject and edit" or "Improve edit" to avoid a community consensus is inappropriate.

But consider first that there is a different way to review.